# ToolTip.Show for an inactive window doesn't works

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

Why tooltip, displayed manually with `ToolTip.Show`, is not shown, when window, containing control, is inactive?

```
public class MyControl : Button
{

    private _tip;
    public string ToolTip
    {
        get { return _tip; }
        set { _tip = value; }
    }

    private ToolTip _toolTip = new ToolTip();

    public MyControl()
    {
        _toolTip.UseAnimation = false;
        _toolTip.UseFading = false;
        _toolTip.ShowAlways = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseHover(EventArgs e)
    {
        _toolTip.Show(_tip, this, 0, Height);
        base.OnMouseHover(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        _toolTip.Hide(this);
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    }
}
```

I went for `ToolTip.Show` because I must have tooltip onscreen for unlimited time, which is not possible with normal `ToolTip`. I also love the idea of having tooltip text as a part of control itself. But unfortunately, when showing tooltip this way for inactive window (despite `ShowAlways = true`), it simply doesn't work.

The `OnMouseHower` event is rised, but `_toolTip.Show` does nothing.. unless window is activated, then everything works.

### Bounty

Adding bounty for a solution to display tooltip for an inactive form (preferably with solution when tooltip text is a property of control, not `IContainer`).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, where did I said `disabled control`? I say `inactive window`, but should probably say `inactive form`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Overlooked it

Comment: That's by design.  From [ToolTip Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx), states `ToolTips are not displayed when their container is inactive.`

Comment: @LarsTech, but if I start using normal `ToolTip`, then set `ShowAlways = true;` and then make Form inactive - it works, but will not stay indefinitely on screen. So I need a solution to kill both rabbits - **indefinite tooltip for inactive form**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a private method that does what you want, so to access it, you would have to use reflection to call it:

```
using System.Reflection;

public class MyControl : Button {
  private ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip() {
    UseAnimation = false,
    UseFading = false
  };

  public string ToolTip { get; set; }

  protected override void OnMouseHover(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnMouseHover(e);
    Point mouse = MousePosition;
    mouse.Offset(10, 10);
    MethodInfo m = toolTip.GetType().GetMethod("SetTool",
                           BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    m.Invoke(toolTip, new object[] { this, this.ToolTip, 2, mouse });
  }

  protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    toolTip.Hide(this);
  }
}
```

The tip will display on an inactive window and it will stay on the screen indefinitely until the mouse moves off the control.

Comment: Thanks, but this will only keep tooltip on screen for 5 sec max (and I mention "unlimited time" in the question itself and then in the the comments). I didn't thought myself about `SetToolTip` for tooltip *hosted inside the control* (if I can name it so). So this idea is useful, but not yet a perfect solution which I need.

Comment: It works as a miracle, thanks! Could you please tell me, how you find this `SetTool` method and what is this magical `2` means (I found that it is `ToolTip.TipInfo.Type`, but I can't find what types are actually exists). Another question is why `Offset(10, 10)`? It works (and seems to properly being to the right from cursor and centered vertically to the lowest point), but I have some doubts about custom cursors (yet I didn't figure out what to do to get this magical `10`, `Cursor.Size` is 32;32 and HotSpot is 0;0, so idk).

Comment: @Sinatr I looked at the [source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolTip@cs/1600728/ToolTip@cs).  2 means Tip enum Type.Absolute.  The (10, 10) offset is because the tip would flicker if it appeared directly underneath the mouse cursor.